# What is the reason for error message "Missing Operator" on arithmetic expression?

Tags: batch-file

Why do I get with the code below the error message:

> Missing operator.

```
@echo off
set plvl=1
set pexp=0
set pexpend=100
set aiexp=10
set pexplvl2=3.1
if "%plvl%"=="1" set /a pexp=%pexp% + %pexpend% / %aiexp% * %pexplvl2%
```

Comment: What numbers are in your variables?

Comment: These are the following variables:

plvl=1
pexp=0
pexpend=100
aiexp=10
pexplvl2=3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch mathematics is always in **integers**. Batch sees the `.` in `3.1` and complains because it is expecting an operator (+-/%*)

Try replacing `3.1` with `31/10` - but remember, the result will be truncated. There will be no decimals.

For example `29/10` produces `2` as result of the integer division and not `3` as a floating point division with result `2.9` and a subsequent rounding to nearest integer value would produce.

Comment: does that mean that if it's 3/1, it will automatic round it to the nearest tense which is 3?